# Clone a repository on GitHub, without exposing the fork?

Tags: git, github, repository, clone, privacy

I would like to clone an existing private GitHub repository, including its history, to a separate private repo. If I do this, is there any mechanism by which the owners of the existing repository would be notified the repository has been cloned and/or forked?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done, but only if the repository is *public*. Then the repository owner can see the cloning statistics, but not WHICH user the repository have cloned.

The cloning statistic can be viewed by clicking on the specific repository, choose **Insights** in the navigation bar and click there **Traffic**.

For more information, look at this GitHub blog *[Clone Graphs](https://github.blog/2014-08-12-clone-graphs/)*.